# How to reverse the axes in the following way?

Tags: plotting, syntax

Could you please tell me whether (and how) it is possible to make the redesign of the x axis in the plot? I have not found the relevant information in the documentation.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the `AxesOrigin` option:

```
Plot[Tanh[2 (x - 2)] + 1.1, {x, 0, 4}, 
 PlotRange -> {{0, 4}, {0, 5/2}}, AxesOrigin -> {4, 0}, 
 AxesLabel -> {x, y}, PlotTheme -> "Classic", PlotStyle -> Thick]
```

[image: plot axes origin on right]